# Using SlotMachine component from "react-slot-machine-gen" npm package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, yarnpkg

I need to import and use Slot Machine component available on npm as "react-slot-machine-gen" to my React App. I am trying to use it inside my React Application installed with create-react-app. Used Yarn to add it to the existing project as described in the npm.
My App.js imports the Demo component which returns a SlotMachine component and a button to run it.
In Demo.js component I've added to more reels so that I have 3 rotating reels. I added imageSrc property path to reel-strip.png images (did that each real).
So, in the end my App.js is:

```
import './App.css';
import React, { Fragment, Component } from 'react';
import Demo from './components/Demo';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        Hello App
        <Demo />
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

My Demo.js is:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import SlotMachine from 'react-slot-machine-gen'; // or '../dist/react-slot-machine-gen';

const reels = [
  {
    imageSrc: 'srcimages\reel-strip1.png',
    symbols: [
      {
        title: 'cherry',
        position: 100,
        weight: 2,
      },
      {
        title: 'plum',
        position: 300,
        weight: 6,
      },
      {
        title: 'orange',
        position: 500,
        weight: 5,
      },
      {
        title: 'bell',
        position: 700,
        weight: 1,
      },
      {
        title: 'cherry',
        position: 900,
        weight: 3,
      },
      {
        title: 'plum',
        position: 1100,
        weight: 5,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    imageSrc: 'srcimages\reel-strip2.png',
    symbols: [
      {
        title: 'orange',
        position: 100,
        weight: 6,
      },
      {
        title: 'plum',
        position: 300,
        weight: 5,
      },
      {
        title: 'orange',
        position: 500,
        weight: 3,
      },
      {
        title: 'plum',
        position: 700,
        weight: 5,
      },
      {
        title: 'cherry',
        position: 900,
        weight: 2,
      },
      {
        title: 'bell',
        position: 1100,
        weight: 1,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    imageSrc: 'srcimages\reel-strip3.png',
    symbols: [
      {
        title: 'cherry',
        position: 100,
        weight: 4,
      },
      {
        title: 'bell',
        position: 300,
        weight: 1,
      },
      {
        title: 'orange',
        position: 500,
        weight: 6,
      },
      {
        title: 'plum',
        position: 700,
        weight: 5,
      },
      {
        title: 'plum',
        position: 900,
        weight: 3,
      },
      {
        title: 'cherry',
        position: 1100,
        weight: 2,
      },
    ],
  },
];

class Demo extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      play: false,
    };
  }

  playEvent() {
    this.setState({
      play: !this.state.play,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <SlotMachine reels={reels} play={this.state.play} />

        <button id='play-button' onClick={() => this.playEvent()}>
          Play
        </button>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default Demo;
```

When I run my project with npm start, I receive the compilation error (see image-2).

[image]

Comment: can you reproduce that in a https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: if you use yarn to add the packages then use `yarn start` to start the applicaton.

Comment: it still doesn't run

Answer (score 1):

The error is seen because of the mismatch of the react versions. `react-slot-machine-gen` uses `react@^16.13.1`.

As you have used create-react-app boilerplate code, the current version uses 17th version of react. And `react-slot-machine-gen` uses 16th version.

Downgrade your react and react-dom version to `16.14.0` and verify.
Since you would be using 16.14.0 you need to add `import React from "react"` wherever necessary.

Codesandbox link https://codesandbox.io/embed/exciting-feather-dihcn?file=/src/Slot.js

Comment: Thank you very much, your suggestion fixed the issue.  The problem now solved, I can render the component.